# How to initiate an action from a emailed link using React.js and json webtoken

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, json-web-token

I am trying to setup a system where the user who registers on my website is verified by sending an email to the email address they provide.

What I want to do is sign their email address with JSON webtoken, email them a link to click. When they click the link, it should take them to my website to a page that says "Your account was verified. Happy browsing"

To do this, i figure I need to generate a link that will trigger a react action when clicked. Any idea how this is done? Does it open a page, send the page the signed token, which when verified then triggers the action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have different ways to do it, for the instance we could have

- A "valid account" page/component
- An async action creator able to check on your server
- A part of your state and a reducer which handle the status of this check

With your react-router or other routing system you can mount pour "valid account" component on the matching route, on DidMount of this component dispatch your async action.
This action should be able to dispatch different action (START_CHECKING, SUCCESSFUL_CHECK, ERROR_CHECK, whatever ...) and of course do the api call to your server. Your reducer should handle the different case.

Your "valid account" component can be connected and tell to user the status of the check.

Bonus : In willReceiveProps you could even redirect to home in case of successful validation.

I hope I understood your problems and that will be helpful, if you have more questions no problem

Comment: Thanks! I was missing the connection of having a "valid account" component.. I'll give this a try

Comment: I implemented pretty much what you suggested. When a user registers with an email address, I dispatch an action that mails them a json webtoken. I redirect them to a "Verify" page/component that will ask them to copy-paste the token. Upon successful validation, it redirects them to homepage. My question is - how can I generate a link that automatically goes to my "Verify" page/component and submits the token, without the user having to copy-paste it manually?

Comment: The generated link can have the token as url param, then in your router you should be able to get it and use it in your component ?
A question : why you use a JWT to check user ? (just a question, may be it's a good practice)

Comment: The problem with this method is that the token appears in the URL which is something i want to avoid. I went with JWT as the previous webdev uses it for authentication so I had to go the same route. Personally, I would rather use paswordless logins.

Comment: I don't find a way to doesn't have some identifier/token in url. JWT token you send if the same which identify user ?

Comment: yes the JWT token has the user/email in the payload. Which is why I didnt want to put it in the URL since it is exposed. Anyway, i think i might go a different route and use a automatically generated phrase to verify rather than a JWT, with the constraint that the user has to be logged in already on the browser.

Comment: Yes if your passphrase/specific identifier is specific to account validation and doesn't allow user to be authentified it seems safter but if user isn't auth, it can require more code. I don't have another idea for that, good luck with this issue, i hope the react/redux part of your problem is good now :).